# Approve/Reject workflow for User Reviews

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design

User generated reviews must be reviewed and approved by an administrator before they can be published across our network.

The interface may also serve to allow administators to search for specific reviews by user name, keyword, or approval status.

Our design at the moment is depicted in the following mockup:

[image]

As the user approves or rejects a review, we envisage that the review would be dynamically removed from the list through a fadeout effect (unless the filter is selected to also display approved or rejected items).

I'm looking for a critique of this approach, and suggestions on how we might improve the UX for this workflow. Many thanks.

Updated mockup based on feedback received:

[image]

Comment: Is the IP address used to get the Location too? If so, maybe an IP address isn't needed unless that's being used to ban certain IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

#### Scopes instead of Check Boxes

So that the user selects between `[Undetermined] [Approved] [Rejected]` (one is always active). You could also have a `[All]` scope if needed.

*Users don't want to think what checkboxes they have to check to get what they want, they just want to make a decision between clearly available options.*

Another reason is that scopes and sorting are two different concerns and should therefore be seperated. Also your UI doesn't make clear what the results are sorted by if `new` isn't checked.

Also you should have a heading that reflects the current scope like 'Approved User Reviews'.

#### Icons to convey status of a review

The user shouldn't have to look at the action buttons to determine the state. This isn't intuitive.
I would use a `green check mark` or a `red cross` to express state. This allows the user to quickly scan all results. It also increases responsiveness.

#### Other things:

1. A heading would make the fieldset legends 'User Review' for every item obsolete.
2. There isn't a date on your mockup indicating when a review got posted.
3. I reckon that the ip address so important that it should be displayed on this list.
4. If I click on `more` I would expect something to popup instead of simply expanding the height (so that you can focus on that specific review).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough response! Are radio buttons the most appropriate way to convey scopes? I'm adding a revised mockup based on your feedback.

Comment: I would advise against the use of reds and greens, but more so a neutral color (like blue). And potentially making the approval button a full button and the rejection button a text button. Only reason why I say that is because reds and greens could be very heavy on the eyes. Just be careful with heavy color usage on a huge list like that.